# How to retrieve specific Data from json file ANGULAR2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, filter, ionic2

This is an Ionic 2 project
I want to retrieve specifiq data from the locally json file.  I googled for 8 houres, still can't find the solution !
Here is My json file

```
[{
    "favoris": true,
    "description": "HOLD (NE PAS SUPPRIMER, NE PAS PASSER HORS PROD)",
    "codeD": "D47433C-07",
    "ville": "Poitier",
    "datePhoto": "2017-06-10T15:50:00"
},{
"favoris": true,
    "description": "HOLD (NE PAS SUPPRIMER, NE PAS PASSER HORS PROD)",
    "codeD": "D47433C-07",
    "ville": "Poitier",
    "datePhoto": "2017-06-10T15:50:00"}]
```

My model:

```
export class Site {
  public favoris: boolean;
  public description: string;
  public codeD: string;
  public ville: string;
  public datePhoto: Date;}
```

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Site } from '../models/site.model';

import { Observable, ObservableInput } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class SiteService {
  private _siteUrl = 'api/sites/sites.json';
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Data Provider');
  }

  /**
   * return sites
  */
  getSites(): Observable<Site[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._siteUrl)
               .map(this.extractData)
               .catch(this.logError);
  }
  extractData(response: Response): Site[] {
    var data = <Site[]>response.json();
    data.forEach((d) => {
      d.datePhoto = new Date(d.datePhoto);
    });
    return data;
  }
  logError(error: Response, caught: Observable<Site[]>): ObservableInput<Site[]> {
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }


  /**
   * for the searchbar
  */
  filterItems(searchTerm): Observable<Site[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._siteUrl)
               .map(res:Response)           .filter(item=>item.codeD.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1 || item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1)
               .catch(this.logError);

  }
```

The code works just fine but when I call the filterItems function (the searchbar) I have this ERROR can't create undefined

Comment: Sorry for the lorem ipsum text. The text editor really tired me!

Comment: the code snippet is used for excutable source block. if you can't make it, just use the code sample block.